# Parent tag is missing from JSON

Tags: java, web-services, json, rest, jersey

I have this DTO to be converted to XML/JSON and send response to client from my web service. We are using Jersey.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "response")
public class Response {

@XmlValue
private String value="true";
}
```

It is getting properly converted to XML,

```
<response>true</response>
```

but json is missing out the parent tag, 
it is outputting `true` instead of `response:true`

Is anybody having the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually because we are omitting parent tag while outputing JSON.
Just in this case omitting parent tag is causing problem as there is only one value in the object.

Answer (score 0):

Values don't get modified with the parent names. One thing is metadata (tags), and other thing is data, that doesn't get modified.

Comment: but how to get it to output valid JSON?

Comment: could you post a complete JSON generated by this?

Comment: it is just generating "true" only; no brackets, no braces, no name value pair.